# Trying to create custom bindable template view in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a XAML template in Xamarin Forms that I can reference from multiple screens. The template has a header, a summary, and can receive touch input. In the attached wireframe, there would be a model backing the three blocks of data. I've read through the docs at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/template-binding/, but at this point I feel like I'm missing an important concept. I thought I would just need to create a ContentView template and somehow make the Labels inside bindable to an object at runtime via .BindingContext. What am I missing?

## Content Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Namespace.SettingsPage"
             Title ="Settings">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SettingTemplate">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label
                    x:Name="Header"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.Header}" />
                <Label 
                    x:Name="Summary"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.Summary}"/>
                </StackLayout>                    
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <ContentPage.Content>      
    <StackLayout>      
        <StackLayout>
            <ContentView x:Name="alerts" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource SettingTemplate}"></ContentView>
            <ContentView x:Name="recipients" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource SettingTemplate}"></ContentView>
            <ContentView x:Name="log" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource SettingTemplate}"></ContentView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

## Code Behind

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Namespace.Settings
{
    public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
    {
        protected SettingsViewModel viewModel;

        public SettingsPage(AlertInfo info)
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = viewModel = new SettingsViewModel(info, this);

            // Bind individual models here. AlertSummary VM has logic to pull out
            // header and summary fiels.
            this.alerts.BindingContext = new AlertSummaryViewModel(info, Summary.ALERTS, this);
            this.recipients.BindingContext = new AlertSummaryViewModel(info, Summary.RECIPIENTS, this);
        }       
    }
}
```

[image: Wireframe]

Comment: The question is not clear. What are you trying to do exactly that doesn't work? Example, here is my page, here is control I want to add based on that template and I don't see that. Also please provide all necessary xml and code behind to reproduce

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I added xaml and code behind.

Comment: To reproduce missing definitions: SettingsViewModel, AlertInfo, AlertSummaryViewModel, Summary.ALERTS.After you provide those please tell me what doesn't work? From the image I see that all data is populated or it is desired image?

Comment: This is a wireframe of a desired outcome. 
I'm not looking to debug so much as looking for guidance on whether this is possible with Xamarin Forms, and if so, where to look for examples.

Comment: It is possible and example you provided in your link in the question. If you do everything right you will get it done. If you have a problem then please provide a code to quickly recreate and help you with you problem. I still don't even know what you are getting on screen and what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is the starting point.

```
    public partial class ControlTemplateTest : ContentPage
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(ControlTemplateTest), "Alerts");
        public static readonly BindableProperty SummaryTextProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create("SummaryText", typeof(string), typeof(ControlTemplateTest), "Three alerts set");

        public string HeaderText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
        }

        public string SummaryText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SummaryTextProperty); }
        }

        public ControlTemplateTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.ControlTemplateTest">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="SettingTemplate">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#DCF394" >
          <Label FontSize="48" TextColor="Black" Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.Parent.HeaderText}" />
          <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.Parent.SummaryText}"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0,40" Padding="0,40">
      <ContentView  x:Name="alerts" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource SettingTemplate}"></ContentView>
      <ContentView x:Name="recipients" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource SettingTemplate}"></ContentView>
      <ContentView x:Name="log" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource SettingTemplate}"></ContentView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: And a suggestion. In your case I wouldn't use this method. I would either implement single view or ListView. I don't see the point to have more than one templated control on the same page.

Comment: Or use DataTemplate https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/introduction/

Comment: I ended up sub-classing ContentView with my new "SettingView" and creating specialized sub-classes like "AlertSettingView" and "RecipientsSettingView", both with Header and Summary fields. Each subclass defines how it displays its own Header and Summary fields.

Comment: Yes, keep it simple